# how to remove specific object in an ArrayList while using a scanner in java

Tags: java, object, arraylist, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to remove a MemberPlayer(object) from my ArrayList(memberList) thorugh my input(scanner)

I have tried looking around google and Stack but can't seem to find anything that uses scanner.

```
    public void removeMember(){
    System.out.println("Which MemberPlayer are you looking for?:");
    System.out.print("Input first name: ");
    String fName = input.nextLine().toUpperCase();
    System.out.print("Input last name: ");
    String lName = input.nextLine().toUpperCase();

    for (MemberPlayer m: memberlist){
        if(m.getFirstName().contains(fName) && m.getLastName().contains(lName)) {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("This MemberPlayer exist:");
            System.out.println(fName + " " + lName);

            System.out.print("Do you want to remove this MemberPlayer?  [yes/no]");
            input.nextLine().toUpperCase();
            if (input.equals("Yes")) {
                memberlist.remove(); //I can't figure out how to write this line?
            }else{
                break;
            }
        }else {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("This MemberPlayer doesn't exist");
            System.out.println();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I read my memberlist from a file.txt with the following info: first name, last name, age and team.

```
ANDERS
ANDERSEN 23 1

BERT BERSEN 16 2

HANS HANSEN 25 1

TIM TIMSEN 20 2
MORTEN MORTENSEN 34 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is  what ended up working for me after some trial and error.

```
public void removeMember()throws FileNotFoundException {
    System.out.println("Which MemberPlayer are you looking to remove?:");
    System.out.print("Input first name: ");
    String fName1 = input.nextLine().toUpperCase();
    System.out.print("Input last name: ");
    String lName2 = input.nextLine().toUpperCase();

    for (MemberPlayer m : memberlist){

        if (m.getFirstName().equals(fName1) & m.getLastName().equals(lName2)) {
            System.out.println();
            memberlist.remove(m);
            System.out.println("You removed: "+m.getFirstName()+" "+m.getLastName());
            System.out.println();
            saveMember();
            break;
        } else {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("This MemberPlayer doesn't exist");
            System.out.println();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [**List#remove()**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove-java.lang.Object-), from the docs :

> boolean remove(Object o)
>
> Removes the first occurrence of the specified
> element from this list, if it is present (optional operation). If this
> list does not contain the element, it is unchanged. More formally,
> removes the element with the lowest index i such that (o==null ?
> get(i)==null : o.equals(get(i))) (if such an element exists). Returns
> true if this list contained the specified element (or equivalently, if
> this list changed as a result of the call).

---

Also, you don't need a `for-loop` here. Your method can be simplified to a much more OO approach :

```
public void removeMember() {
    System.out.println("Which MemberPlayer are you looking for?:");
    System.out.print("Input first name: ");
    String fName = input.nextLine().toUpperCase();
    System.out.print("Input last name: ");
    String lName = input.nextLine().toUpperCase();

    // create an object with input received
    MemberPlayer m = new MemberPlayer(fName, lName);

    // use contains of List
    if (memberlist.contains(m)) {
        memberlist.remove(m);
    } else {
        System.out.println("This MemberPlayer doesn't exist");
    }
}
```

*Make sure you override the `.equals()` and `.hashcode()` methods in `MemberPlayer`.*

Comment: I've been messing about with your solution and i can't seem to get it to work. I've added a construtor in MemberPlayer to handel the new object and i'm not quite sure by what you mean by overriding the .equals() and .hashcode()

Comment: Which IDE are you using? You can auto-generate those methods. You can try a Google search regarding how to generate them. I'd be happy to help if you still are facing issues with it.

Comment: [Why should we override equals and hashcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265503/why-do-i-need-to-override-the-equals-and-hashcode-methods-in-java) might help you out further.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using an `Iterator` for this, as using the `List.remove(Object o)` can throw the `ConcurrentModificationException` as you are changing the state of the object while iterating.

So [`Iterator.remove()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove--) will be a safe bet. From the *Java SE 1.8* docs:

> Iterators allow the caller to remove elements from the underlying
>   collection during the iteration with **well-defined semantics**.

So removing an object directly from the `List` using `List.remove()` will cause unpredictable iteration and throw `ConcurrentModificationException` while iterating it.

If you are not *iterating* then it is fine to use the `List.remove(Object o)` to remove the object from the `List`.

```
//Initializes the iterator, checks if next element is present by calling Iterator.hasNext()
for(Iterator<MemberPlayer> itr = memberList.iterator(); itr.hasNext(); ){
         m = itr.next(); //The current element of the List
         if(m.getFirstName().contains(fName) && m.getLastName().contains(lName)) {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("This MemberPlayer exist:");
            System.out.println(fName + " " + lName);

            System.out.print("Do you want to remove this MemberPlayer?  [yes/no]");
            input.nextLine().toUpperCase();
            if (input.equals("Yes")) {
                 itr.remove(); //Removes the current element if the condition is satisfied.
            }else{
                 break;
            }
         }else {
             System.out.println();
             System.out.println("This MemberPlayer doesn't exist");
             System.out.println();
             break;
         }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that you cannot remove a `Collection<T>` element while you're iterating it using the `for-each` loop. In that case a `ConcurrentModificationException` might be thrown.

You need to explicitly use an `Interator<T>` or a `ListIterator<T>`, depending on the usecase.
A `ListIterator` allow also insertion of elements or setting of elements.

```
for (final Iterator<MemberPlayer> iterator = memberList.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
   final MemberPlayer m = iterator.next();

   if (m.getFirstName().contains(fName) && m.getLastName().contains(lName)) {
      ...

      iterator.remove();
   }
}
```